# Can macros expand to a combination of patterns?

Tags: macros, pattern-matching, rust

As of Rust 1.0, there is no way to group multiple patterns into one binding:

```
// It does not compile
match x as char {
    b @ ('A' | 'Z') => println!("A or Z: {}", b),
    _ => println!("Try again")
}

// Correct version
match x as char {
    b @ 'A' | b @ 'Z' => println!("A or Z: {}", b),
    _ => println!("Try again")
}
```

I was wondering if a macro could do the dirty job of binding all the different possibilities. Here is a partial attempt:

```
macro_rules! bind_alternatives {
    ($x:ident, $e:expr) => ($x @ $e);
    ($x:ident, $e1:expr, $e2:expr) => (
        $x @ $e1 | $x @ $e2
    );
}

fn main() {
    let x = 'a';

    match x {
        bind_alternatives!(z, 'a', 'c') => println!("Matched"),
        _ => println!("No luck")
    };
}
```

This does not compile:

```
example.rs:4:18: 4:19 error: macro expansion ignores token `|` and any following
example.rs:4         $x @ $e1 | $x @ $e2
                                      ^
example.rs:12:9: 12:40 note: caused by the macro expansion here; the usage of `bind_alternatives` is likely invalid in this context
example.rs:12         bind_alternatives!(z, 'a', 'c') => println!("Matched"),
```

I understand that macros can be expanded into patterns, and the first brace of `bind_alternatives` does work. Is it possible to generalize to more than 1 possibility? If not, what prevents it?

Comment: I don't have a complete answer, but `'a' | 'c'` is not a pattern, it's match-specific syntax for combining patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure when this changed, but the example code in the initial post compiles now, on Rust `1.63.0`.

```rust
macro_rules! bind_alternatives {
    ($x:ident, $e:expr) => ($x @ $e);
    ($x:ident, $e1:expr, $e2:expr) => (
        $x @ $e1 | $x @ $e2
    );
}

fn main() {
    let x = 'a';

    match x {
        bind_alternatives!(z, 'a', 'c') => println!("Matched"),
        _ => println!("No luck")
    };
    
    foo(b'A')
}

fn foo(x: u8) {
    // It DOES compile
    match x as char {
        b @ ('A' | 'Z') => println!("A or Z: {}", b),
        _ => println!("Try again")
    }
    
    // Correct version
    match x as char {
        b @ 'A' | b @ 'Z' => println!("A or Z: {}", b),
        _ => println!("Try again")
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=69668c3da91c09d81784ad0fe2617c9f)

Answer (score 5):

A macro is able to expand to things like patterns, expressions and items, but not everything; specifically, macros expand to complete AST nodes, but what you’re dealing with here is not a complete AST node.

Each branch of a `match` expression can have one or more patterns, separated by pipes, and an optional pattern guard (`if condition`). This is all special `match`-specific syntax, and thus not a complete AST node, and thus not something that a macro can expand to.

The parser is looking for a pattern at that point of its parsing, so it expands the macro as a pattern, which concludes before the `|`, which doesn’t fit in a pattern grammar. The macro has thus produced more than can be consumed, and the rest is discarded with an error.